# Why is Maven Build prompting for multiple launch configurations when there is actually none?

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2e, pom.xml

In my project (inherited BTW, so some aspects of it are still unknown), under Eclipse/m2e I right-click `pom.xml` > `1 Maven Build` and I get a dialog:

> Select a launch configuration to run:
>
> - m2 myproj (1):
> - m2 myproj (2):
> - m2 myproj (3):
> - m2 myproj:

But looking at the project's `Properties` > `Run/Debug Settings`, there are **no launch configurations at all**. None whatsoever.

What does that mean?

Should I select one of the 4 configurations listed above? If so, which one and why?

**UPDATE 1:** Interestingly, when I right-click `pom.xml` and select `Run As` > `Run Configurations...`, I see those configurations defined:

[image]

I still don't know what this means, though. I don't recall ever defining them. How did they get there?

**UPDATE 2:**
Apparently those launch configurations were created inadvertently by clicking some close/cancel button or similar. So I deleted all except for one, then ran it:

```
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 0.093s
    [INFO] Finished at: Wed Dec 05 16:44:24 EST 2012
    [INFO] Final Memory: 1M/15M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or
 <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. 
Available lifecycle phases are: 
validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, 
process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources,
 generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, 
test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, 
post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, 
site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, 
please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
```

Strange. I know that `pom.xml` has goals and builds fine when selecting `Run As` > `Maven Install`.